# Retrieve data from single line of text from Sharepoint list and save it as CSV file

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I have a flow that registeres the responses from FORMS and saves it to Sharepoint LIST. When new items are automatically added, it also creates a CSV file in different location. I am trying to work it a little different so it only saved latest item added to the LIST as single CSV file. I do not want to have a full list exported as CSV file but new input as new file, and so on.

Is this feasible in any way?

It does not have to be done using power apps/ power automate but perhaps the python/ powershell script?

Comment: You can use Power Automate Desktop to perform those actions.

Answer (score 0):

Truex, as you want to trigger the CSV file creation on the "list item added" action, it is not feasible using python or PowerShell script. One option is to schedule the script to check the new item added in the list and then generate a csv for new items added after the last run.

Comment: Enlighten me on why PowerShell or Python might not be working? Do an http request to your list with an access token and you can retrieve the latest items in the list?

Comment: Iona, PowerShell or Python option will work but not on the trigger of item added. If you make a standalone call, it will give you the details. Here requirement is to do it on item added trigger, your thoughts?

Comment: A webhook with python to get the latest item and write that to a location could do the job. Basically a latest item trigger as required and send that item to your webhook. From the id you can retrieve the item itself via HTTPS again